# Why does my String method allow a return value of a String and int?

Tags: java, string, methods, int

I'm new to Java, and currently learning how methods work in Classes. I wrote a simple method that should return a String value, but when i concatenated it with a int value it still works.

I tried flipping the return value to start off with the int and that also worked. Does java know to convert the int value into a String value?

```
public class MyOwnJavaProject 
{

    int favoriteNumber;

....
// This method worked
public String showFavNumber()
    {
        return "My favorite number is " + this.favoriteNumber;
    }

// This method also worked
public String showFavNumber()
    {
        return this.favoriteNumber + " is my favorite number";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a `String` in both. When you `+` (concatenate) a `String` and an `int` it returns a `String`. This would not work:

```
public String showFavNumber()
{
    return this.favoriteNumber;
}
```

but this would:

```
public int showFavNumber()
{
    return this.favoriteNumber;
}
```

Comment: Ah i get it. So whenever i use a int value but then concatenate it, then the whole return value just becomes a String?

Comment: @MatthewMortensen correct...

Comment: Programmers often use this as a convenient way to convert an int to a String. For example, return this.favoriteNumber + ""; There are other ways to do it, but it works well.